# Two buttons ( that generate inputtexts when clicked ) don't work on the same Facelet

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have two buttons that generate inputtexts when clicked. The problem is, when these two buttons are on the same `xhtml`, wichever is the first one, it is the only one that works.

**If you need**, here is an explanation on the **Code 1** below:

It represents two `inputtexts` to get the `name`
 and `email` of the author of a `Document`. `moreAuthors` represents
 the method `getMoreAuthors()` that belongs to the Managed Bean `inserirBean`.

`getMoreAuthors()` returns a `List<AuthorBean>`.
  The `List<AuthorBean>` is a property from the Managed Bean `inserirBean`. 
 The class `AuthorBean` creates the instances of `Author`, it has a property called 
`Author author`.

`AddAuthor()` adds one more `AuthorBean` to the `List<AuthorBean>` in 
Managed Bean `inserirBean`.

**If you need**, here is an explanation on the **Code 2** below:

It follows the same structure from **Code 1**. Here, there's only one
 `inputtext` that is used to get a **subject** of a `Document`.
 `moreSubjects` returns a `List<SubjectBean>`. The class `SubjectBean`
 creates the instances of the class `Subjects`. 
 `SubjectBean` has a property `Subject sub`,
 and `Subject` has a property called `String subject`.

`AddSubject()` adds one more `SubjectBean` to the `List<SubjectBean>` in 
Managed Bean `inserirBean`.

**Code 1- If this is the only one on the `xhtml`, it works:**

```
           <h:form >
            <h:dataTable value="#{inserirBean.moreAuthors}" var="authorBean">
                <h:column>
                    Nome do Autor:
                    <h:inputText value="#{authorBean.author.name}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    Email do Autor:
                    <h:inputText value="#{authorBean.author.email}" />
                </h:column>
                <f:facet name="footer">
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <h:commandButton value="+" action="#{inserirBean.addAuthor()}" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                </f:facet>
            </h:dataTable>
           </h:form>
```

**2-  If this is the only one on the `xhtml`, it works too:**

```
           <h:form >
            <h:dataTable value="#{inserirBean.moreSubjects}" var="subjectBean">
                <h:column>
                    Palavras-chave:
                    <h:inputText value="#{subjectBean.sub.subject}" />
                </h:column>
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <h:commandButton value="+" action="#{inserirBean.addSubject}" />
                </h:panelGroup>
            </f:facet>
            </h:dataTable>
           </h:form>
```

**BUT**, if I put these two blocks on the same `xhtml`, the one that appears first on the browser, always works, and the second, never - and I've already tried to change their position, but whichever I put first place on screen is the one that works.

**What's causing this problem?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put the two `datatables` in **code 1 and 2** inside the same `<form>` block and both worked.